# Python Code is not working in Jupyter notebook partially

Tags: python

I am building a code to download some data and rename the file. When I test it in Jupyter notebook by running part A and part B in separate cells it works, but it is not working while running both in single cell.

Part A

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Submit & Clear History']").click()
time_to_wait = 10
time_counter = 0
while not os.path.exists(r"C:\Users\rkmaheshwaran\Downloads\CSV\Py-files"):
    time.sleep(1)
    time_counter += 1
    if time_counter > time_to_wait:break
print("done")
```

Part B

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\rkmaheshwaran\Downloads\CSV\Py-files")
for file in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\rkmaheshwaran\Downloads\CSV\Py-files"):
    src=file
    if src=='printcsvreports.csv':
        dst="inflowdata-" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + ".csv"
        os.rename(src,dst)
print("renamed")
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message stating?

Comment: I dont get any error message, but the file was not renamed while running these codes together.
Got the output as:
done
renamed